# Calculate curvature necessary for line segment to cover given linear distance

Tags: geometry, curves

I have to apologize in advance for probably not knowing all the proper terms, and not being properly skilled in reading equations. I hope whoever is kind enough to answer this is also patient enough to explain it in relatively simple terms.

For illustration purposes, consider the below line segments. Assume they are all of the exact same length (I don't have the drawing tools to draw them exactly). I start with a straight segment, then curve it more and more, but keep the starting point of the segment the same.

[image: Line segments]

The rate of curvature in a given segment is constant (i.e. each curved segment, if continued, would form a perfect circle).

Observe that the vertical distance the segment covers decreases as the angle of the curve increases. "Bending over" makes it "shorter" without decreasing the actual length of the segment.

Now consider that there is a specific vertical distance I am trying to get the line segment to cover. I want to curve the line so that no part of it goes above the yellow line.

[image: Marked line segments]

Note that *no* part of the line can be above the yellow, not just the end point of the line.

My question is: given a line segment of known length, and a known limit for vertical distance, by what formula can I calculate the angle of curvature required to make the line segment fit below said limit. Or, to put it more simply: how can I figure out how much I need to curve the black line before it fits below the yellow line?

Comment: What are your attempts to solve it and where did you find this?

Comment: I'm trying my hand at video game development, that's where the question comes from. I was kind of hoping that whoever saw this would take a look and go "oh, that's just this standard equation you're never head of" and I'd be able to research and adapt it further. I'm not entirely sure where to start otherwise. I've noticed that if the curve is between 90° and 360°, the distance covered is equal to the radius of the full circle the segment would form. But that's solving the equation backwards, and I'm not sure how to adapt that for angles <90°.

Comment: Sure, I've added another answer to list the function that wrote to find $\text{sinc}^{-1}$ using Newton's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation below illustrates how to obtain the bending line.

[image]

Suppose the length of the arc is $L$, and the maximum altitude of the arc above the starting point is $H$.  Since this is an arc, it has a radius and an angle $\theta$.  Then

$ L = R \theta $

Now for $0 \le t \le \theta$ , the altitude of a point on the line is

$ y(t) = R \sin(t)  = \dfrac{L \sin(t)}{\theta} $

The maximum of this expression has two cases

Case I:  $0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

In this case,

$ \dfrac{H}{L} = \dfrac{\sin(\theta) }{\theta } $

Case II:  $ \dfrac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \pi $

In this case,

$ \dfrac{H}{L} = \dfrac{1}{\theta} $

So from the required ratio of $\dfrac{H}{L}$ we can solve for $\theta$, and then plot the arc.

Note that

$ \dfrac{2}{\pi} \le \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} \le 1 $ for  $0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

and

$ \dfrac{1}{\pi} \le \dfrac{1}{\theta} \le \dfrac{2}{\pi} $ for $ \dfrac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \pi  $

Therefore, based on the value of $\dfrac{H}{L}$ over the interval

$[ \dfrac{1}{\pi} , 1 ] $ we can select which function to invert to find $\theta$, as follows

$  \theta = \left\{ \begin{aligned} 
&\text{sinc}^{-1}(\dfrac{H}{L}) \\ &\dfrac{1}{(H/L)} \end{aligned} \right. \qquad 
\begin{aligned} &\dfrac{2}{\pi} \le \dfrac{H}{L} \le 1 \\ &\dfrac{1}{\pi} \le \dfrac{H}{L} \le \dfrac{2}{\pi} \end{aligned}  $

where $\text{sinc}(\theta) = \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} $

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I’ll be working to understand it. Could you please define the variable *t* for me?

Comment: $t$ is just a parameter that runs over the interval $[0, \theta]$.

Comment: I believe I'm close to understanding this. $\text{sinc}^{−1}$ means the inverse of the sinc function, right? Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but how am I supposed to solve for that here? (I'm using Desmos as a tool to play around with this and make sure I understand it before trying to implement it in video game code, in case that's useful info).

Comment: I used Newton's method to find $\text{sinc}^{-1}$.

Comment: Would you be able to share the function you came up with, or give any more additional information or pointers on how to proceed in solving that inverse function? (I'm not a mathematician, I don't know what it means to apply Newton's method to this problem and haven't been able to find a starting point to try).

Comment: I've shared my code in a second solution.  Does this answer your question ?

Comment: I might not be able to read equations too well, but VBA I *CAN* read! Thank you very much, I was able to implement this. Still needs some work, but here's a taste of your equations in action:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhoXE.gif

Comment: Very nice.  Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I used to find $\theta = \text{sinc}^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{H}{L}\bigg) $

In the code, the variable $\text{h2l}$ is used to represent $\dfrac{H}{L}$.

```
Public Function sincinv(ByVal h2l As Double) As Double
Dim f, fp As Double

' Find t such that sin(t)/t - h2l = 0

' function:    f = sin t - h2l t = 0
' derivative:  fp = cos t - h2l

p = WorksheetFunction.Pi()

lconverged = 0

t = h2l * p / 2

For i = 1 To 100

f = Sin(t) - h2l * t

fp = Cos(t) - h2l

If Abs(f) < 0.00000001 Then
   lconverged = 1
   Exit For 
End If

dt = -f / fp

If Abs(dt) < 0.00000001 Then
   lconverged = 1
   Exit For
End If

t = t +  dt

Next i

If Not (lconverged = 1) Then
   MsgBox ("did not converge")
   Exit Function
End If

sincinv = t

End Function
```